# Streaming arbitrary data using multipart/x-mixed-replace MIME type

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, streaming, multipart-mixed-replace

I have seen that it is possible to stream jpegs using the multipart/x-mixed-replace MIME type responses from the server and with a simple `<img src=host/streamAddress />` on the client side. What I understand is that the browser takes care of getting each frame, displays it and the updates. Streaming jpegs this way actually worked for me.

But now I am trying to stream some text data (small compressed point clouds) using this method. I'm kind of stuck at how to handle it on the client side. I'd like to use the different fragments (between the boundaries) as some sort of "frames", that would be rendered sequentially.

I am using three.js as my rendering engine, and I use their loader, that seems to use a standard XMLHTTPRequest, and has 3 callbacks, **load** when the content is loading, **progress** while the content is loading, and an **error** callback.

When I'm sending an XMLHTTPRequest, the **onLoad** callback is never called, but the **onProgress** callback is infinitely called. I can see the buffer (containing the correct data) when loging to the console, but it seems like it is infinitely growing. The request is never ending.

<s>This seems to be expected with the multipart/x-mixed-replace but the XMLHTTPRequest doesn't seem to take it into account. I kind of excpected the onLoad callback to be called at each update...</s>

It would be great if someone could provide a minimal working exemple of a client side code that could work.
Alternatively, I would be interested in other similarly simple solutions, as I use an "handwritten" (actually using boost) c++ server for my application.

Thanks for the help !

**Edit**: I found out that there is no more support for multipart/x-mixed-replace... A suggestion that I found is to do get the responseText from the onProgress event.

But doing this leaves the browser believe that the page is loading all the time, seems to end up with an error all the time. Is there a way to have the progress callback being called all the time and making the browser believe that everything went fine ?